# Extract slug from permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I want to extract the slug from post permalink when pretty permalinks is enabled.
If the permalink is:
http://sitename.com/category/best-post

Grabbing only "best-post".
(My end goal is to query posts by posts urls)

Any help will be appreciate!

Comment: You can look here:
[How to retrieve the slug of current page?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42117/how-to-retrieve-the-slug-of-current-page)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split the string by the slashes and take the last bit:

```
$url = "http://sitename.com/category/best-post";
$parts = explode("/", $url);
echo $parts[count($parts) - 1]; // best-post
```

Comment: This will work as long as there are no url parameters on the end of the url like page numbers or added tracking info. You may need to explode the slug against to split off anything after a question mark to get a clean slug if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the global $post object like below:
within the loop you can use,
    global $post;
    $post_slug=$post->post_name;

or

```
global $post;
$slug = get_post( $post )->post_name;
```

and outside the loop you can do it like this,
    global $wp_query;
    $post_id = $wp_query->post->ID

```
$post = get_post( $post_id );
$slug = $post->post_name;
```

Not tested 100% but it should work for you

Comment: This assumes you already know the post ID, not helpful if you have just the URL. For instance if you are trying to find the post ID using get_page_by_path, but need the slug for that function